# Changing EditText style each words contained within

Tags: java, android, styles, themes

How could you set a style for all **(Date : )** words withint an EditText?
If let say the content is:

```
textView.setText("Date : " + obj.getDate() + "\n" + "Date : " + obj2.getDate());
```

I do understand that we can manipulate certain style from one index to another index of the String contained within a Textview. The example given by this code is only changing one word only.

Not all **(Date : )** Words are changed :

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById( R.id.TextView );
Spannable spannable = (Spannable)textView.getText();
StyleSpan boldSpan = new StyleSpan( Typeface.BOLD );
spannable.setSpan( boldSpan, 0, 6, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE );
```

along with its important parameter **spannable** stated within its layout (XML):

```
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/TextView"
        android:bufferType="spannable" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />
```

How could you set a style for all **(Date : )** words withint an EditText?

Comment: you mean when you write a text in edittext it will change color for Date? can you post an image of what you would like it to be?

Comment: I want to change the color of every "Date :" text @Rod_Algonquin...
inside the EditText component.

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate `SpannableString` using `[TextUtils.concat(Charsequence ...)][1]` like this:

```
SpannableString span1 = new SpannableString(Date :);
SpannableString span2 = new SpannableString(obj.getDate());

span1.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, span1.length() -1, 0))
span2.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, span1.length() -1, 0))

mTextView.setText(TextUtils.concat(span1," " ,span2));
```

Havn't tried the code but it should be pretty straight forward:

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById( R.id.TextView );
SpannableString date = new SpannableString("Date: ");

StyleSpan boldSpan = new StyleSpan( Typeface.BOLD );
spannable.setSpan(boldSpan, 0, span1.length() -1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

textView.setText(TextUtils.concat(date, obj.getDate(), "/n", date, obj2.getDate()));
```

Comment: please explain to me why do you use span1.length() on both span? @Rawa

Comment: setSpan works like this: spannableString.setSpan(<Style to apply>, <StartChar>, <EndChar>, 0)) if you want to color the whole string apply it from 0 to the last char, length - 1.

Comment: The basic idea is that you style your strings the way you want them and then concatenate them with TextUtils.concat before applying the it to the textview.

Comment: Updated my answer for a more concrete solution. Hope it helps, if it does please accept my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

create some helper function to format your date , something like

```
public static CharSequence getDateString(Date date){
    Spannable text = new SpannableString("Date : "+ date.toString());
    StyleSpan boldSpan = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
    text.setSpan(boldSpan,0,text.length(),Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
    return text;
}
```

then concat text using TextUtils and then set

```
 tv.setText(TextUtils.concat(tv.getText(), getDateString(new Date()),"\n", new Date().toString()));
```